# TSQL & SSRS - Same query returning two different data sets

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssms

This is a little awkward to explain so i shall try my best.

I have written a query in SSMS 17. The query runs fine and returns the data correctly from 1990-01-01 to 2018-03-04. This is correct and 2018-03-04 is the most recent case for this query to pull.

When dropping this exact query into SSRS (Visual Studio) i originally put a between data parameter which cascaded to two further options to select of case type and location. I put these as seperate datasets to link the parameters to cascade them. This all worked fine. It was only on my final checks of the report did i realise i couldn't get any data past 2017-10-27. **There is no filters on any of the data.**

In the end i have now removed all my parameters so it is the main data set only and put a code in to pull the last 2 years instead. This still ends at 2017-10-27. Does anyone have any ideas how the same query run in SSMS returns the data correctly but copied and pasted in SSRS VS it suddenly wont pull past 2017-10-27?

There are only 1,615 rows in that time so its not like there is masses of data and i have hit some limit.

Truly stumped with this one. I haven't posted my code as it works in SSMS without issue so i dont believe the issue lies there.

This is the code used currently. The long Case When for the Dates is to counter for UTC database time to BST.

```
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SET ARITHABORT ON;

 WITH cvr AS
 (
 SELECT DISTINCT 
                        hcx.mps_Person,
                        cpx.mps_Name [Name],
 CASE       WHEN hcx.mps_SchemeCode IS NULL THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(hcx.mps_MembershipNumber)) 
            WHEN hcx.mps_SchemeCode = '' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(hcx.mps_MembershipNumber)) 
            WHEN hcx.mps_SchemeCode IS NOT NULL THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(hcx.mps_SchemeCode))+'/'+LTRIM(RTRIM(hcx.mps_MembershipNumber)) ELSE NULL END AS [Membership Number],
                        hcx.mps_MemberCoverStatus [Cover Status],
                         cmd.[Country of Incident] [Case Country],
 CASE       WHEN hcx.mps_CoverSource = 0 THEN 'Cover Account' 
            WHEN hcx.mps_CoverSource = 1 THEN 'SAM Cover' 
            WHEN hcx.mps_CoverSource = 2 THEN 'MDU Transfer Cover' ELSE NULL END AS [Cover Source],
 CASE       WHEN hcx.mps_startdate > (DATEADD(HH,1,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,hcx.mps_startdate) AS CHAR) + '/03/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) AND hcx.mps_startdate < (DATEADD(HH,2,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,hcx.mps_startdate) AS CHAR) + '/10/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) THEN (DATEADD(HH,1,hcx.mps_startdate)) ELSE hcx.mps_startdate END AS [CM Cover Start Date],
 CASE       WHEN hcx.mps_enddate > (DATEADD(HH,1,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,hcx.mps_enddate) AS CHAR) + '/03/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) AND hcx.mps_enddate < (DATEADD(HH,2,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,hcx.mps_enddate) AS CHAR) + '/10/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) THEN (DATEADD(HH,1,hcx.mps_enddate)) ELSE hcx.mps_enddate END AS [CM Cover End Date],
                        cmd.[Case Number] AS [Case Number],
                        cmd.IncidentId,
                        cmd.[Medical/Dental] AS [Medical/Dental],
                        cmd.[Primary Case Type] AS [Incident Primary Case Type],
                        cmd.[Case Types] AS [Incident Case Types],
                        cpx.mps_dn_CaseTypesInvolved AS [Member Involved Case Types],
 CASE       WHEN cpx.mps_involvedfrom > (DATEADD(HH,1,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,cpx.mps_involvedfrom) AS CHAR) + '/03/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) AND cpx.mps_involvedfrom < (DATEADD(HH,2,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,cpx.mps_involvedfrom) AS CHAR) + '/10/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) THEN (DATEADD(HH,1,cpx.mps_involvedfrom)) ELSE cpx.mps_involvedfrom END AS [Involved From],
 CASE       WHEN cpx.mps_involvedto > (DATEADD(HH,1,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,cpx.mps_involvedto) AS CHAR) + '/03/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) AND cpx.mps_involvedto < (DATEADD(HH,2,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,cpx.mps_involvedto) AS CHAR) + '/10/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) THEN (DATEADD(HH,1,cpx.mps_involvedto)) ELSE cpx.mps_involvedto END AS [Involved To],
 CASE       WHEN cpx.mps_claimsmadenotificationdate > (DATEADD(HH,1,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,cpx.mps_claimsmadenotificationdate) AS CHAR) + '/03/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) AND cpx.mps_claimsmadenotificationdate < (DATEADD(HH,2,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,cpx.mps_claimsmadenotificationdate) AS CHAR) + '/10/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) THEN (DATEADD(HH,1,cpx.mps_claimsmadenotificationdate)) ELSE cpx.mps_claimsmadenotificationdate END AS [Claims Made Notification Date],
 CASE       WHEN cmd.[MPS Claim Date] > (DATEADD(HH,1,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,cmd.[MPS Claim Date]) AS CHAR) + '/03/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) AND cmd.[MPS Claim Date] < (DATEADD(HH,2,(DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000107',DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,cmd.[MPS Claim Date]) AS CHAR) + '/10/01'),30))/7*7,'19000107')))) THEN (DATEADD(HH,1,cmd.[MPS Claim Date])) ELSE cmd.[MPS Claim Date] END AS [MPS Claim Date]
                        ,cmd.[Total Claim Payments (Sterling Equivalent in £)] AS [TotalClaimPayments]
                        ,cmd.[Total Non-Claim Payments (Sterling Equivalent in £)] AS [TotalNonClaimPayments]
                        ,FLOOR(cmd.[MPS Apportionment %]*100) AS [Liability]

 FROM       OneMPS_MSCRM.dbo.mps_historiccoveraccountExtensionBase AS hcx
     INNER JOIN OneMPS_MSCRM.dbo.mps_historiccoveraccountBase AS hca ON hca.mps_historiccoveraccountId = hcx.mps_historiccoveraccountId AND hca.statuscode = 1 /*Active*/
     INNER JOIN OneMPS_MSCRM.dbo.mps_casepartyExtensionBase AS cpx  ON hcx.mps_Person = cpx.mps_Person
     INNER JOIN OneMPS_MSCRM.dbo.mps_casepartyBase AS cpb ON cpx.mps_casepartyId = cpb.mps_casepartyId AND cpb.statuscode = 1 /*Active*/ AND cpx.mps_PrimaryRole = 0
     INNER JOIN dbo.CasesMasterData AS cmd ON cmd.incidentid = cpx.mps_Case

 WHERE  hcx.mps_CoverBasis = 'Claims Made'
     AND hcx.mps_IsSuperseded = 0 /*Not Superseded*/
     AND cpx.mps_involvedto >= hcx.mps_StartDate /*Intersects with Period of Involvement*/
     AND cpx.mps_involvedfrom <= hcx.mps_EndDate /*Intersects with Period of Involvement*/
     AND cpx.mps_InvolvedFrom >= '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000'
 )
 ,cts AS
 (
 SELECT 
             cvr.mps_Person,
             cvr.[Cover Source],
             cvr.Name,
             cvr.[Membership Number],
             cvr.[Cover Status],
             cvr.[CM Cover Start Date],
             cvr.[CM Cover End Date],
             cvr.[Case Number],
             cvr.IncidentId,
             cvr.[Involved From],
             cvr.[Involved To],
             cvr.[Claims Made Notification Date],
             cvr.[MPS Claim Date],
             cvr.[Medical/Dental],
             cvr.[Case Country],
             cvr.[Incident Primary Case Type],
             cvr.[Incident Case Types],
             cvr.[Member Involved Case Types],
 CASE       WHEN LEAD(cvr.[CM Cover Start Date],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cvr.mps_person, cvr.[Membership Number], cvr.[Case Number] ORDER BY cvr.[CM Cover Start Date]) = cvr.[CM Cover Start Date]
        AND LEAD(cvr.[CM Cover End Date],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cvr.mps_person, cvr.[Membership Number], cvr.[Case Number] ORDER BY cvr.[CM Cover Start Date]) = cvr.[CM Cover End Date] THEN NULL
            ELSE DATEDIFF(d,cvr.[CM Cover Start Date],cvr.[CM Cover End Date]) END [CM Cover Days],
 (SELECT MIN(cvr_sd.[CM Cover Start Date]) FROM cvr cvr_sd WHERE cvr_sd.mps_Person = cvr.mps_Person AND cvr_sd.[Membership Number] = cvr.[Membership Number] AND cvr_sd.[Case Number] = cvr.[Case Number]) [CM Cover Start Date (Min)],
 (SELECT MAX(cvr_ed.[CM Cover End Date]) FROM cvr cvr_ed WHERE cvr_ed.mps_Person = cvr.mps_Person AND cvr_ed.[Membership Number] = cvr.[Membership Number] AND cvr_ed.[Case Number] = cvr.[Case Number]) [CM Cover End Date (Max)],
 (SELECT COUNT(cvr_rw.mps_Person) FROM cvr cvr_rw WHERE cvr_rw.mps_Person = cvr.mps_Person AND cvr_rw.[Membership Number] = cvr.[Membership Number] AND cvr_rw.[Case Number] = cvr.[Case Number]) [Total Rows],
             cvr.TotalClaimPayments, 
             cvr.TotalNonClaimPayments, 
             cvr.Liability
 FROM   cvr
 )
 ,chk AS 
 (
 SELECT 
            cts.mps_Person,
            cts.[Case Number],
            cts.IncidentId,
            cts.[Membership Number],
     SUM(cts.[CM Cover Days]) AS [CM Cover Days],
    DATEDIFF(d,cts.[CM Cover Start Date (Min)],cts.[CM Cover End Date (Max)])-MAX(cts.[Total Rows]) AS [CM Cover Days (If Unbroken)]
 FROM   cts
 GROUP BY
             cts.mps_Person,
             cts.[Case Number],
             cts.IncidentId,
             cts.[Membership Number],
             cts.[CM Cover Start Date (Min)],
             cts.[CM Cover End Date (Max)],
             cts.[Case Country]
 )
 SELECT
            cts.Name,
            cts.[Membership Number],
            cts.[Cover Status],
            cts.[Cover Source],
            cts.[CM Cover Start Date],
            cts.[CM Cover End Date],
 CASE   WHEN chk.[CM Cover Days] >= DATEDIFF(d,cts.[CM Cover Start Date (Min)],cts.[CM Cover End Date (Max)])-cts.[Total Rows] THEN cts.[CM Cover Start Date (Min)] ELSE NULL END [CM Continuous Cover Start Date],
 CASE   WHEN chk.[CM Cover Days] >= DATEDIFF(d,cts.[CM Cover Start Date (Min)],cts.[CM Cover End Date (Max)])-cts.[Total Rows] THEN cts.[CM Cover End Date (Max)] ELSE NULL END [CM Continuous Cover End Date],
            a2a.[A2A Decision],
            a2a.[A2A Decision Reason],
            cts.[Case Number],
            cts.[Involved From] AS [Involved From Date],
            cts.[Involved To] AS [Involved To Date],
            cts.[Claims Made Notification Date] AS [Claims Made Notification Date],
            cts.[MPS Claim Date],
            cts.[Medical/Dental],
            cts.[Case Country],
            cts.[Incident Primary Case Type],
            cts.[Incident Case Types],
            cts.[Member Involved Case Types],
            mbr.[# Members Involved],
    SUM(ISNULL(cts.TotalClaimPayments,0)+ISNULL(cts.TotalNonClaimPayments,0)) AS [TotalSpend],
            ISNULL(cts.TotalClaimPayments,0) AS [Claim Payments - Total (£)],
    CAST(cts.Liability*(cts.TotalClaimPayments/100) AS NUMERIC(14,2)) AS [Claim Payments - Apportioned to Member (£)],
            ISNULL(cts.TotalNonClaimPayments,0) AS [Non-Claim Payments - Total (£)],
            cts.Liability AS [MPSClaimLiability]
 FROM   cts
        INNER JOIN chk ON chk.[Case Number] = cts.[Case Number] AND chk.[Membership Number] = cts.[Membership Number] AND chk.mps_Person = cts.mps_Person

OUTER APPLY
 (
 SELECT TOP 1
 CASE    WHEN   adx.mps_Decision = 0 THEN 'No' 
         WHEN   adx.mps_Decision = 1 THEN 'Yes' 
         WHEN   adx.mps_Decision = 2 THEN 'Pending' 
         WHEN   adx.mps_Decision = 3 THEN 'No - Member Declined' 
         WHEN   adx.mps_Decision = 4 THEN 'Yes - Ex Gratia' 
         WHEN   adx.mps_Decision = 5 THEN 'No - Member Uncontactable/Not Responding'
         ELSE NULL END AS [A2A Decision],
            adx.mps_DecisionReason AS [A2A Decision Reason]

 FROM   OneMPS_MSCRM.dbo.mps_authoritytoassistdecisionBase AS adb
 INNER JOIN OneMPS_MSCRM.dbo.mps_authoritytoassistdecisionExtensionBase adx ON adb.mps_authoritytoassistdecisionId = adx.mps_authoritytoassistdecisionId AND adb.statuscode IN (2) /*2=Valid*/
 INNER JOIN OneMPS_MSCRM.dbo.mps_casepartyExtensionBase cpx ON cpx.mps_casepartyId = adx.mps_CaseParty
 INNER JOIN OneMPS_MSCRM.dbo.mps_casepartyBase cpb ON cpx.mps_casepartyId = cpb.mps_casepartyId AND cpb.statuscode = 1 /*Active*/ AND cpx.mps_PrimaryRole = 0

 WHERE          cpx.mps_Case = cts.IncidentId

 ORDER BY  adx.mps_DecisionOn DESC 
 ) AS a2a
 OUTER APPLY
 (
 SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(cpx.mps_casepartyId) AS [# Members Involved]
 FROM   OneMPS_MSCRM.dbo.mps_casepartyExtensionBase cpx 
 INNER JOIN OneMPS_MSCRM.dbo.mps_casepartyBase cpb ON cpx.mps_casepartyId = cpb.mps_casepartyId AND cpb.statuscode = 1 /*Active*/ AND cpx.mps_PrimaryRole = 0

 WHERE cpx.mps_Case = cts.IncidentId
 ) AS mbr

 GROUP BY        cts.Name,
                 cts.[Membership Number],
                 cts.[Cover Status],
                 cts.[Cover Source],
                 cts.[CM Cover Start Date],
                 cts.[CM Cover End Date],
 CASE WHEN chk.[CM Cover Days] >= DATEDIFF(d,cts.[CM Cover Start Date (Min)],cts.[CM Cover End Date (Max)])-cts.[Total Rows] THEN cts.[CM Cover Start Date (Min)] ELSE NULL END,
 CASE WHEN chk.[CM Cover Days] >= DATEDIFF(d,cts.[CM Cover Start Date (Min)],cts.[CM Cover End Date (Max)])-cts.[Total Rows] THEN cts.[CM Cover End Date (Max)] ELSE NULL ENd,
                 a2a.[A2A Decision],
                 a2a.[A2A Decision Reason],
                 cts.[Case Number],
                 cts.[Involved From],
                 cts.[Involved To] ,
                 cts.[Claims Made Notification Date],
                 cts.[MPS Claim Date],
                 cts.[Medical/Dental],
                 cts.[Case Country],
                 cts.[Incident Primary Case Type],
                 cts.[Incident Case Types],
                 cts.[Member Involved Case Types],
                 mbr.[# Members Involved],
                cts.TotalClaimPayments ,
                CAST(cts.Liability*(cts.TotalClaimPayments/100) AS NUMERIC(14,2)),
                cts.TotalNonClaimPayments,
                cts.Liability
                ORDER BY cts.[Involved From] ASC
```

Sample Data shortened. Its Essentially a Data Extract.

```
Name|Membership Number|CoverStatus|Cover Date             |Involved From 
Bob |984684638        |Active     |2017-03-01 00:00:00.000|2017-10-27 00:00:00.000
Test|135486968        |Active     |2017-07-01 00:00:00.000|2018-03-04 00:00:00.000
```

The first row will show in SSRS fine, the second row will not be visible at all. The main dates this would work off is the last one [Involved From]. 
The only thing i can think of is the BST conversion is maybe somehow affecting it as its the only thing i do with the date.

Comment: Please post some sample code and schema and data. It could relate to
- silent errors caused by SET options, NULL handling, etc. Running code in SSMS can give different results to other clients becuase of things like ARITHABORT

Comment: @gbn Added the code but its a long one and some sample data to try help.

Comment: A few questions;  1. If you run the code from the SSRS dataset query designer and type in your parameters, do you get the correct results or the 'truncated' version?  2. Are you certain your SSRS dataset is pointing to the same server/database as SSMS and not some dev or UAT server?

Comment: @AlanSchofield Hi Alan, think your answer came in at the same time as i posted my own comment below but it was pointing at the wrong server. The Shared Data Source said it was our "live" server but when i then checked the connection string it was pointing to test. Test having less data than our live but SSMS queries live directly. Egg on my face! think I very much overthought what could of gone wrong and couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted out... I've done the same thing myself many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all apologies i appear to have well over thought this. Thank you for those that responded with ideas.

It turned out to be the Shared Data Source, we have a live and a test environment. The Data Source said it was pointing at live, but when i checked the connection string (why i didn't think of it earlier) it was actually looking up the test server which has limited data.

Couldn't see the wood for the trees with this one :) so lesson learned. REMEMBER TO CHECK YOUR CONNECTION STRING AND NOT JUST THE NAME.

Answer (score 0):

Load this Query into SP and Give the Source from SP,I hope this will solve the issue since the code is huge.

Answer (score 0):

> You have  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
>   May be Same query returning two different data sets due to this isolation level session. As if any table is updated (insert or update or delete) under a transaction and same transaction is not completed that is not committed or roll backed then uncommitted values will displaly (Dirty Read) in select query of "Read Uncommitted" isolation transaction sessions.
>   So, SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;